# How to get generated jooq table by table name

Tags: kotlin, jooq

I have the table name as a string and i know that there is a generated table with the same name.
I want to be able to match the table based on its type so i can benefit from jooqs generated code.
Like this in Kotlin (this is a simplified example):

```
when (myTable) {
  is Book -> DSL.condition(myTable.authorId.eq(5))
  is Author -> DSL.condition(myTable.id.eq(5))
}
```

When i construct a table from the string with `val myTable = DSL.table("book")` it is not of type `Book`.
Is there some way to get a generated table by its name?

More Info:
The reason i want to get from string to table is that i want to generate a sql query from a graphql query, so the sql table name is inferred from the graphql type name.
I want to do something different based on the table type because i want to have a function that works on a table and produces a condition even if the table has an alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the generated schema to look up tables by name:

```kotlin
Book book = THE_SCHEMA.getTable("book") as Book
```